# Pending transaction towards a not syn wallet

Tags: withdrawal

Hi guys need a bit of help I send my ember coins from cryptopia to old ember wallet address which is not syn my transaction is coming in pending since 2 days..how do I cancel my transaction so the coins r back to available.[image][image]